# Laravel scope inside a custom where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I never have problem with that, but now I have a situation here:

The code below need to filter some data based on a query param named 'status' and then use the related scope to filter, but, for some reason the scope not work inside the where, only outside.

```
        return Vacancy::whereCompanyId($id)
            ->where(function($query) use ($statusFilter) {
                if (!empty($statusFilter) && !empty($statusFilter['status'])) {
                    if ($statusFilter['status'] == 'published') {
                        $query->published();
                    } else if ($statusFilter['status'] == 'drafted') {
                        $query->drafted();
                    } else if ($statusFilter['status'] == 'finished') {
                        $query->where('vacancy_status_id', 3);
                    } else if ($statusFilter['status'] == 'deactivated') {
                        $query->deactivated();
                    }
                }
            })
            ->orderBy('id','DESC')
            ->paginate(3);
```

Scopes:

```
    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('vacancy_status_id', '=', VacancyStatusEnum::Published);
    }

    public function scopeDraft($query)
    {
        return $query->where('vacancy_status_id', '=', VacancyStatusEnum::Draft);
    }

    public function scopeFinished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('vacancy_status_id', '=', VacancyStatusEnum::Done);
    }

    public function scopeDeactivated($query)
    {
        return $query->where('vacancy_status_id', '=', VacancyStatusEnum::Disabled);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use 'finished' scope.

I found a small mismatch in the 'draft' scope, I renamed that to:

```
public function scopeDrafted($query)
{
    return $query->where('vacancy_status_id', '=', VacancyStatusEnum::Draft);
}
```

Also, I suggest that you might rewrite a bit to make it leaner.

```
return Vacancy::whereCompanyId($id)
    ->when(!empty($statusFilter['status']), function($query) use ($statusFilter) {
        $scope = $statusFilter['status'];

        $query->$scope();
    })
    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
    ->paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Closure callbacks:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

 return Vacancy::whereCompanyId($id)
        ->where(function (Builder $query) use ($statusFilter) {
            if (!empty($statusFilter) && !empty($statusFilter['status'])) {
                if ($statusFilter['status'] == 'published') {
                    $query->published();
                } else if ($statusFilter['status'] == 'drafted') {
                    $query->drafted();
                } else if ($statusFilter['status'] == 'finished') {
                    $query->where('vacancy_status_id', 3);
                } else if ($statusFilter['status'] == 'deactivated') {
                    $query->deactivated();
                }
            }
        })
        ->orderBy('id','DESC')
        ->paginate(3);
```